# Experiencing SIGTRAP error when executing gtest with smart pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17, smart-pointers, googletest

I have a gtest that runs to test allocation of some attribute in one of my classes.  This test executes fine when stepping through the debugger with both assertions passing.  However, when the code block finishes, a segmentation error is thrown:

```
Running main() from C:/Users/user/repos/atvalue_cpp/Google_tests/lib/src/gtest_main.cc
Signal: SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap)
Signal: ? (Unknown signal)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

The test is as follows:

```
TEST_F(UnitTest, RatedCapacity){
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> parent {new Unit(1, "Parent Unit")};
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> child1 {new Unit(11, "Child 1", parent, 30)};
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> child2 {new Unit(22, "Child 2", parent, 10)};
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> child3 {new Unit(33, "Child 3", parent, 60)};
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> child4 {new Unit(44, "Child 4", parent, 43)};
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> child5 {new Unit(55, "Child 5", child2, 43)};
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> child6 {new Unit(55, "Child 5", child2, 43)};

    EXPECT_EQ(parent->getRatedCapacity(), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(child2->getRatedCapacity(), 10);
}
```

And the class definition of the `Unit` class:

```
class Unit {
private:
    unsigned id{};
    std::string name;
    double ratedCapacity;
    std::shared_ptr<Unit> parent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> children;
public:
    Unit();
    Unit(unsigned int id, std::string  name);
    Unit(unsigned int id, std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Unit> parent, double capacity);
    ~Unit();
```

The implementation of the constructor called in the test is as follows:

```
Unit::Unit(unsigned int id, std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Unit> parent, double_t capacity) :
        id {id},
        name {std::move(name)},
        parent {parent},
        ratedCapacity(capacity) {
    if (parent){
        this->parent = parent;
        auto child = std::shared_ptr<Unit>{this};
        this->parent->addChild(child);
    }
    Unit::counter++;
}
```

I get the sense that this error is due to one of the shared pointers referencing a piece of de-allocated memory.  However I was under the impression (as a relative newcomer to C++) that the whole point of using smart pointers was to not have to worry about this in the first place?  Clearly some more learning required on my end so I would really appreciate some smart pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
auto child = std::shared_ptr<Unit>{this};
```

puts the object currently under construction under the ownership of a new shared pointer.

However, after construction of new objects in the lines such as

```
std::shared_ptr<Unit> child1 {new Unit(11, "Child 1", parent, 30)};
```

the `Unit` objects are *again* put under the ownership of a new shared pointer.

These two shared pointers are not aware of each other and both assume they have ownership of the `Unit` instance. If you copy the shared pointers, they of course do track the fact that they share ownership, but the same is not true if you create new unrelated `std::shared_ptr` objects with the same raw pointer.

As a result, the shared pointers will try to delete the `Unit` objects twice.

---

To be able to create new `std::shared_ptr`s sharing ownership with already existing ones that you have no access to, you can use `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

`Unit` should publically inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and then you can use

```
auto child = shared_from_this();
```

However, since you are doing this in the constructor *before* the a `std::shared_ptr` took ownership of the object, it will not work (either undefined behavior or since C++17 an exception is thrown).

Instead you can replace the constructor by a factory method, returning a `std::shared_ptr` that puts the new object under its control before creating `child`.

---

You can avoid making this mistake by only using `std::make_shared` instead of constructing `std::shared_ptr` objects explicitly. It also has better exception handling guarantees in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped a lot to track down the issue.  One of the main issues is that the data structure created by the `Unit` class is an acyclic graph.  So each node holds a reference to its own parent and any number of children.  So when some of the heap objects are deleted, inevitably there will be some pointer (either a parent or child) still referencing it.  The construction and destruction of these objects therefore requires a bit more thought.

Comment: @Paul Well, that is another issue. You are effectively creating circular shared pointer dependencies between parent and children. Doing that will result in memory leaks since the loop will never be destroyed. This is resolved by using `std::weak_ptr` to split up the dependency loops. For example you can have the `parent` attribute be a `std::weak_ptr` created from the shared_ptr.

Comment: @Paul Also, it seems wrong that the child is responsible for adding itself to the parent on construction. Instead you can first create free nodes, which are then passed to a parent's member function which adds the new node to the graph. This would also avoid the `std::enable_shared_from_this` issue in the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, valid point.  Thanks.